# .Net cross platform using Xamarin studio and Visual Studio differences

Tags: .net, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, console-application

I am trailing out a cross platform app using Xamarin studio on Mac and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 on Windows.

**What I have tried**

When I create a .Net console app on the Mac, I can run it on both Mac and see it in the terminal app and Windows in the console app.

When I create a console app on Windows, I can run it on Windows in the console, but the terminal on macOS does not start

When I create an console app on Mac, push it to the windows machine edit it and push / pull it back to the Mac it does not show the terminal.

I know windows uses .exe files and macOS uses .app but for lack of better words, why does this process seem to break?

I can't find any setting (in the program and from forums) that would fix this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `mono <path to exe>.exe` on OSX to run your apps in Terminal

Comment: But what if I want to develop on both platforms - do I need to do this everytime?

Comment: Have you tried `.NET Core` for that scenario?

Comment: No not yet - may need to look into that now. Was thinking that Xamarin Studio would deal with this scenario